# Can I connect remote sql server database without management studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, localdb

I was working with `Visual Studion 2015` and I was using `localdb` feature to do data access and manipulations. Can I access remote database, which is on azure, in the same way or other without installing `ssms`?

As marked duplicate, I will make an effort to make this question unique.

I am not asking how to connect remote db using localdb, I was telling I used localdb to connect local databse.

The main question is "Can I access remote database, which is on azure, in the same way or *other* without installing ssms?"

Seems like @Jude's comment answered it, worth a try.

Comment: how is remote sql server related to localdb?

Comment: LocalDb is *local*. You can connect to any other version by using the correct connection string

Comment: He is not on about accessing to LocalDB. He is on about the way to access to DB. Yes you can. SQL Server Object Explorer under View menu is what you need. Straight forward process. Basically, you don't need SSMS.

Comment: @Jude Thanks, this answers my question :) It was never about localdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is not on about accessing to LocalDB. He is on about the way to access to DB. Yes you can. SQL Server Object Explorer under View menu is what you need. Straight forward process. Basically, you don't need SSMS

-- Credit (Jude - commentor on this post).